# How do I make Django Form Fields Disappear with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, html

I have a form in my Django application. What I'm attempting to do is create a form that is filled out in parts. I'm trying to allow the user to navigate the form by clicked on "next" and "prev" buttons to hide and show different steps of the field. The following is my HTML:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!--Meta data and stylesheet linking-->
    </head>

    <body onload="loadFunction()">
        <header>
            <!--Header-->
        </header>
        <section id="form-section">
            <div id="form-container">
                <form class="form" method="post"> 
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div id="1">
                        <h2>Step 1 of 3</h2>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="info_field" class="sr-only">Info Field</label>
                            {{ form.info_field }}
                        </div>
                            <!--There are a few more fields like this -->

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <a onclick='stepChange(1, "next")' href="#">Next</a>
                            <a onclick='stepChange(1, "last")' href="#">Last</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="2">
                        <h2>Step 2 of 3</h2>
                            <!--Several form fields-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <a onclick='stepChange(2, "prev")' href="#">Previous</a>
                            <a onclick='stepChange(2, "next")' href="#">Next</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="3">
                        <h2>Step 3 of 3</h2>
                        <!--Several form fields-->
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <a onclick='stepChange(3, "first")' href="#">First</a>
                            <a onclick='stepChange(3, "prev")' href="#">Previous</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer id="mainFooter">
            <p>Footer Info.</p>
        </footer>
        <script>
            function stepChange(var step, var cmd) {
                if(cmd == "first") {
                    var x = document.getElementById("3");
                    var y = document.getElementById("1");
                    x.style.display = "none";
                    y.style.display = "block";
                }
                else if (cmd == "prev") {
                    var x = document.getElementById(step);
                    x.style.display = "none";
                    var y = step - 1;
                    x = document.getElementById(y);
                    x.style.display = "block";
                }
                else if (cmd == "next") {
                    var x = document.getElementById(step)
                    x.style.display = "none";
                    var y = step + 1;
                    x = document.getElementById(y);
                    x.style.display = "block";
                }
                else if (cmd == "last") {
                    var x = document.getElementById("1");
                    var y = document.getElementById("3");
                    x.style.display = "none";
                    y.style.display = "block";
                }
            }
            function loadFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementById("1");
                var y = document.getElementById("2");
                var z = document.getElementById("3");
                x.style.display = "block";
                y.style.display = "none";
                z.style.display = "none";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My issue is that when I load the page, all of the steps are being displayed at the same time. When I click on any of the "a" tags (next, prev, etc), nothing changes, and I do not understand what I am doing wrong. I have also tried using a "window.onload = function" method, and that had produced the same result. I would greatly appreciate any help that is given, thank you!

Comment: Don't you get undefined variables for `next` & `prev`... I think if you pass `'next'` & `'prev` as strings it'll work

Comment: This was a good thing to point out, and I have made the adjustments. However, this did not fix the issue I'm having. Nothing is hidden still.

Comment: You don't need to specify `var` for the arguments to the function. Also to be safe use `===` instead of `==` to prevent type coercion

Comment: So I don't need to declare the type "var" to be used in the function? And I made the changes to the code from "==" operator to "===", but this also did not fix the issue.

Comment: It worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, giving the type "var" in front of the arguments in the function resulted in an error that prevented my functions from working. Upon removing this, my original solution worked perfectly. Here is the finished code, for those who wish to learn from it as I did.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!--Meta data and stylesheet linking-->
    </head>

    <body onload="loadFunction()">
        <header>
            <!--Header-->
        </header>
        <section id="form-section">
            <div id="form-container">
                <form class="form" method="post"> 
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div id="1">
                        <h2>Step 1 of 3</h2>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="info_field" class="sr-only">Info Field</label>
                            {{ form.info_field }}
                        </div>
                            <!--There are a few more fields like this -->

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <a onclick='stepChange(1, "next")' href="#">Next</a>
                            <a onclick='stepChange(1, "last")' href="#">Last</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="2">
                        <h2>Step 2 of 3</h2>
                            <!--Several form fields-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <a onclick='stepChange(2, "prev")' href="#">Previous</a>
                            <a onclick='stepChange(2, "next")' href="#">Next</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="3">
                        <h2>Step 3 of 3</h2>
                        <!--Several form fields-->
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <a onclick='stepChange(3, "first")' href="#">First</a>
                            <a onclick='stepChange(3, "prev")' href="#">Previous</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer id="mainFooter">
            <p>Footer Info.</p>
        </footer>
        <script>
            function stepChange(step, cmd) {
                if(cmd == "first") {
                    var x = document.getElementById("3");
                    var y = document.getElementById("1");
                    x.style.display = "none";
                    y.style.display = "block";
                }
                else if (cmd == "prev") {
                    var x = document.getElementById(step);
                    x.style.display = "none";
                    var y = step - 1;
                    x = document.getElementById(y);
                    x.style.display = "block";
                }
                else if (cmd == "next") {
                    var x = document.getElementById(step)
                    x.style.display = "none";
                    var y = step + 1;
                    x = document.getElementById(y);
                    x.style.display = "block";
                }
                else if (cmd == "last") {
                    var x = document.getElementById("1");
                    var y = document.getElementById("3");
                    x.style.display = "none";
                    y.style.display = "block";
                }
            }
            function loadFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementById("1");
                var y = document.getElementById("2");
                var z = document.getElementById("3");
                x.style.display = "block";
                y.style.display = "none";
                z.style.display = "none";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Here's a solution:

I'm only showing you the principle. Apply the `.disp_none` class to containers you don't want shown. Then get the objects by ID, and remove that class when the next button in is clicked.

### css

```
step_1 { display: block; }
step_2 { display: block; }
.disp_none { display: none; }
```

### html

```
<form method="POST" action=".">

    <div id="step_1">
        <label>Step 1 of 3</label>

        <p><a id="to_step_2" href="#step_2">NEXT</a></p>

        <!-- blah blah blah -->
    </div>


    <div id="step_2" class="disp_none">
        <label>Step 2 of 3</label>

        <p><a href="#step_3">NEXT</a></p>

        <!-- blah blah blah -->
    </div>

    <!-- and so on... -->

</form>
```

### Javascript

```
<script>

   var to_step_2 = document.getElementById("to_step_2");
   var show_step_2 = document.getElementById("step_2");

   function myFunction() {
      show_step_2.classList.remove("disp_none");
   }

   to_step_2.onclick = myFunction


</script>
```

### And to make classes disappear:

You do it with the syntax `element.classList.remove("mystyle");`

### To improve this for older browsers:

Add more event listeners. You can find a lot on this page at [w3 schools.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand this solution. So, the `disp_none` is a list that contains the classes that are to be hidden, and by removing them, they appear. So, if I make classes disappear with `element.classList.remove('mystyle')`, how would I make the class reappear if the user wanted to go back a page? Is there a way to add the elements back to the `disp_none` class?

Comment: Close. You're mixing things up though. `.disp_none` is a css class, not a list, nor an array. You apply this class by default to every step container, except for `#step_1`. So when the page is loaded, only step 1 shows. Then you write an event handler for each step container, so it will remove the `.disp_none` to show the next step once they hit a button. In my example I used an `<a>` inside a paragraph, because it was faster to type. But the same principle applies if you used any other element. There would be no need to reappear previous containers, because they would all be on the same page.

Comment: If this makes it easier, here's what you're doing: You start with everything visible on the page. All containers, everything. Then you `.disp_none` the things you don't want shown to users yet. Then you make some buttons, and event handlers for them, and when they're clicked: you remove that class so they can be seen.... So step 1 needs a button and an event handler to show step 2 (by removing the `.disp_none` class). Step 2 needs an event handler for step 3, and so on. And that's it. No need for extra pages. Everything is on one.